# WCF call gets "Access is denied" over HTTPS on .NET 4

Tags: wcf, https, wcf-binding, wcf-security, asp.net-4.0

Never had problems before but after upgrading to .NET 4, I am getting "Access is Denied" when trying to invoke a WCF method over HTTPS.  If I use HTTP instead of HTTPS, everything works fine.  Any possible solutions for this?  I can provide more specific information if requested.

web.config

```
    <system.serviceModel>
            <behaviors>
              <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="some_product.SomeServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
              </serviceBehaviors>
              <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="some_product.SomeServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                  <enableWebScript />
                </behavior>
              </endpointBehaviors>
            </behaviors>
            <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
            <services>
              <service name="some_product.SomeService">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="some_product.SomeServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_SomeService" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="some_product.SomeService"/>
              </service>
            </services>
            <bindings>
              <basicHttpBinding>        
<binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_SomeService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                     maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                     maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
       <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                     proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        </security>
     </binding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SomeService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                  <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                  </security>
                </binding>
              </basicHttpBinding>
              <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SomeService" maxReceivedMessageSize="300000" allowCookies="true"  >
                  <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="300000" />
                </binding>
              </webHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <client>
              <endpoint address="/someurl/SomeService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_SomeService" contract="some_product.SomeService" name="BasicHttpBinding_SomeService"/>
<endpoint address="/someurl/SomeService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_SomeService" contract="some_product.SomeService" name="BasicHttpsBinding_SomeService"/>
            </client>
          </system.serviceModel>
```

Note:  Works PERFECTLY fine over HTTP.  Problem ONLY exists under HTTPS.

Comment: Can you show us your server- and client-side config?? Without **anything** at all, it's a game of guess at best....

Comment: @marc_s - web.config info added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your setup, you have no security defined -- thus you can only connect using http:

```
<basicHttpBinding>        
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SomeService" .....>
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                     maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                     maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
       <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        </security>
     </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

If you want to use https, you need to enable transport security:

```
<basicHttpBinding>        
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Secure" .....>
       <readerQuotas ..../>
       <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                     proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        </security>
     </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

**Update:** Now that you have **defined** your secure HTTPS binding configuration:

```
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_SomeService" ......>
            <readerQuotas ......../>
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                           proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            </security>
```

you also need to **configure** an endpoint to use that binding configuration, of course!

```
<services>
   <service name="some_product.SomeService">
      <endpoint 
           address="" 
           behaviorConfiguration="some_product.SomeServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" 
           binding="webHttpBinding" 
           bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_SomeService" 
           contract="some_product.SomeService"/>

      <!-- add this endpoint !! -->       
      <endpoint 
           address="secure" 
           binding="basicHttpBinding" 
           bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_SomeService" 
           contract="some_product.SomeService"/>
    </service>
 </services>
```

Just defining the binding configuration without having an endpoint that actually refers to it doesn't really help......

Comment: So it will have to be an entirely new <binding> section?

Comment: @Brian: yes, a second <binding> inside the <basicHttpBinding> - that's called a "binding configuration". You'll also need another endpoint that references that binding configuration

Comment: @Brian: can you update your original post with the new, modified web.config ?? Just curious how you added the second endpoint and if there's anything that might be off with that.

Comment: @Briad David Berman: updated my answer - you need to **add** an endpoint that really **uses** that new binding configuration!